# Submenu disappears as soon as I reach it with a mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu and a submenu. I got it toggled in Jquery by combining some answers from stackoverflow and from api.jQuery. But now I am really stuck and I cant find a way out to solve it.
Whenever I reach the menu, submenu toggles(Good thing), but whenever I reach for the submenu links it disappears.

And it doesnot work in fiddle because of the styling, thats why I didnt put it there.

HTML

```
<ul id="menüü">
    <li class="menu">
        <p><a href="meist.html">Meist</a>

        </p>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="asi1">Asi 1</li>
            <li class="asi2">Asi 2</li>
            <li class="asi3">Asi 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
        <p><a href="seadmed.html">Seadmed</a>

        </p>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="item1">Item 1</li>
            <li class="item2">Item 2</li>
            <li class="item3">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="submenu"></div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    height:50px;
    color:#191919;
    text-align:center;
    background:#990000;
    -moz-border-radius-top-left: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    position:relative;
}
.submenu {
    font-size:14px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:62px;
    right:25%;
    z-index:300
}
.submenu {
    background-color:#cecece;
}
.submenu > li {
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#submenu {
    color:white;
    height:40px;
    width:900px;
    background:#630000;
    margin-top:50px;
    position:relative;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.menu").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find(".submenu").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: }
.submenu {
    font-size:14px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:62px;
    right:25%;
    z-index:300
}
.submenu {
    background-color:#cecece;
} this is dubble work btw :p

Comment: it doesent work at all now.. I fecked up something -.-

Comment: what is the use of '#submenu'? its overlapping your navigation

Comment: Its the background of submenu, its just below of menu. its behind the submenu text.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3khp/13/ I does work in my browser, but when I paste it in fiddle, id does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `mouseenter` to `mouseover` then when you hover a child element it will not close. And use `mouseover` to show and `mouseout` to hide.

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSNfF/)

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(".menu").mouseover(function () 
    {
        $(this).find(".submenu").show();
    });

    $(".menu").mouseout(function () 
    {
        $(this).find(".submenu").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Toggling toggles between show and hide, so the first time the `mouseenter` event is triggered it will show and the second time it hides. You need to add a conditional statement to make sure it doesn't hide it if the mouse is over it. Better way to do it is to use `mouseenter` to show and `mouseout` to hide.

Comment: Clarify that ? where should I put mouseout ? I tried if mouseenter .submenu it will show() but it didnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect example by any means, but this pure css version should provide a good base to get you started?

http://jsfiddle.net/bNpnZ/2/

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="meist.html">Meist</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="asi1">Asi 1</li>
            <li class="asi2">Asi 2</li>
            <li class="asi3">Asi 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="seadmed.html">Seadmed</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="item1">Item 1</li>
            <li class="item2">Item 2</li>
            <li class="item3">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

ul {
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.menu {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#eee;
}
.menu > li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
    position:relative;
}
.menu > li:first-child {
    margin:0;
}
.menu > li > a {
    padding:10px 20px;
    float:left;
    color:#666;
}
.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999em;
    left:0;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.menu > li:hover .submenu {
    top:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have update the jquery and added style for `.menu a`, also `<p>` in not required in side the li.

jQuery

```
$('.menu').hover(
function () {
    $(this).children('.submenu').fadeIn('fast');
},
function () {
    $(this).children('.submenu').fadeOut();
});
```

css

```
.menu a{
    display:block;
    line-height:50px;
}
.submenu {
    font-size:14px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:25%;
    z-index:300
}
```

html

```
 <ul id="menüü">
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="meist.html">Meist</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="asi1">Asi 1</li>
            <li class="asi2">Asi 2</li>
            <li class="asi3">Asi 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
        <a href="seadmed.html">Seadmed</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="item1">Item 1</li>
            <li class="item2">Item 2</li>
            <li class="item3">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/U3khp/16/)